# Edge fails, with numerous Event errors

Tags: microsoft-edge

Trying to open Edge by any method fails. An empty Edge window pops up only briefly.

I've tried several suggested fixes over many hours, so far in vain.

I'm hoping that the most likely source of clues for those with more tech savvy than me might lie in this composite screenshot I've prepared of Event Viewer. It shows that whenever an attempt is made to open Edge, Event 1000 occurs and is then cyclically followed many times by 21, 37, 38 and 22.

[image: Composite, annotated screenshot]

Comment: [Reset, Repair or Reinstall Edge browser in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10)

Comment: I would agree you need to Reset and/or Reinstall Edge.  Did Edge work at any point recently?  Did you at any point run any tool that claimed to improve your privacy on Windows 10?  The event logs are pointing to Edge not actually being installed and/or your configuration does not allow any UWP application to work.  I assume UAC is enabled on your system, since it is required, for UWP applications to function.

Comment: I'm curious what edgelso.dll is and where it is on disk?  I assume it's part of Edge given the version number for the DLL and for MicrosoftEdge.exe are very similar going by your event log entry.  I don't have the file on my computer but I have: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe with file version 11.0.17763.55.

Comment: This worked for me: 
First perform the now familiar PowerShell reset of Microsoft Edge:

Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml” -Verbose}

But the crucial step for me and others was to add a new Registry key, using this elevated command prompt:
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Spartan" /v RAC_LaunchFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

Comment: Brevity requirement here may be popular with regulars but...

Comment: My fix came from a post by KJSTech1:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4c6fd9e-f44d-43e8-9527-1b8b93725f93/microsoft-edge-crashes-after-upgrading-to-creator-update-1703
reporting a solution found by rafaeljsc.

Comment: The comment by HelpingHand about edgelso.dll, which I too don't have, led me to googling it and that eventually led me to the fix. Probably not allowed here, but thanks ;-)